# Define small row height in Reporting Services 2005

Tags: reporting-services, report

I want to specify a small row height in a Reporting Services report of about 3pt. While the report looks ok in the previewer, once deployed, the row height resets to the standard row height.

I have adjusted the "CanGrow" and "CanShrink" settings as well as the padding, lineHeight, font size, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that one way to fix this is to put a single underscore in each column of the row.

The problem is actually with the way a blank row is outputted. If you view the source of the outputted report you will see that the row you are trying to keep short will output like so:

```
<TR style="HEIGHT:1.06mm">
<TD class="a19">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class="a20">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class="a21">&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
```

Those blank spaces (`&nbsp;`) is what is causing the height to be incorrect. If you were to remove those blank spaces it would output correctly.

By putting an underscore character in each column of the row it removes the blank space that would normally be outputted and then your row height is more accurate. You may want to change the color of the text of each column to match your row background color, just so the underscore will never be visible.